# TextView with scrollbar that can handle onTouchEvents

Tags: java, android, scrollbar, touch-event

I have problem with handling Touch events inside my `TextView` on Android 2.3.3. I've got Activity implements `OnTouchListener` with method

main.java

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getPointerCount()==1){
  textView.setTextSize(mRatio+13);
        mRatio++;        
        Log.d("TouchEvent", "one touch !");
        }
  if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
some code...
  }
  return true; 
 }
```

and my layout(only part of it):

```
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_weight="1.0"
                  android:fadingEdge="none"
                  android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <!-- TEXT EMAIL : -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mail_text"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:clickable="true"

                android:textColor="@color/mailtext"
                android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

When i 'clicked' anywhere outside my textBox(for example on header or footer), the Touch event trigger, font get bigger. I assume than the problem is probably because scrollbars. But when I cut off `android:scrollbars = "vertical"` bar just disappear.

This textView usually contain a lots of text.

How to proper fire onTouchEvents inside this textView.

*Edit:*
when this textView is small my touchEvent work until i get text so big, than the scrollBar is needed. Then all touch event get overrided and You can only scroll textView. No TouchEvent is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handle the problem in other way. OnTouchEvent didn't worked with my TextView so I Override dispatchTouchEvent. It's far more better to performe actions "onTouch".Scrollbar is working and I can add my multitouch events on the whole screen. It's look like:

```
  @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){
          Log.v("NotificationActivity.dispatchTouchEvent()", "got touch");

          if (motionEvent.getPointerCount() == 2) {
    Log.v("touch", "multi touch !");
              int action = motionEvent.getAction();
              int pureaction = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
              // some actions ...
          }

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                //Keep track of the starting down-event.
                Log.v("akcjaa","down");
     // some actions ...
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                //Consume if necessary and perform the fling / swipe action
                //if it has been determined to be a fling / swipe
              Log.v("akcjaa","up");
                break;
            }

        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your TextView is inside some kind of ScrollView or Scrollable container, right?

Then you will face this issue. Android does not like his apples and pears mixed, you should not be trying to receive "onTouch" events that are being consumed by the father layout on top of the view.

I guess you could:

a) Switch to a onClickListener on your TextView

b) Override your parent view layout touch handler to bleed the touch down to its childs. This is not really 100% recommended, and could cause unwanted behaviour.

Sorry if i cannot be of more help.